# Linux shell file. mkdir and pushd commands not doing what I'd like

Tags: linux, shell, sh, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory if it does not exist, and the further down the line, create a log file in that directory. It would be in the *current* users home directory
In pseudocode:

```
If directory "/home/LOGS" does not exist
make directory "/home/LOGS"
```

Then whenever a log file is created, it will save in that directory, not the directory that the program is being run from.
This is what I have so far, and it's just not working...

```
pushd -n  $"../LOGS" >/dev/null 2>&1 

#Create the logs folder
if [ ! -d $"home/LOGS" ]; then
 mkdir -p $"home/LOGS"
fi
```

If it helps, my files are being saved like so:

```
     function savefile {
# Save to file
  if [ -e $username.log ]; then
    echo "Username already exists, returning you to the menu."
    sleep 2
    clear
      menu
  else
    echo $fullname >> $username.log
    echo $password >> $username.log
      curdate=$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    echo $curdate >> $username.log
  echo "Creating your account"
    sleep 2
    clear
  echo "Account created"
  echo
    afterBasic
  fi 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think there could be a problem when you attempt to `pushd` into a directory before you test to see if that directory actually exists?

Comment: I've tried putting it after a bit ago. I'll test it again now.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Good point in general; note, however, that even in the right order there'd be no change in current directory, because `pushd -n` is being used.

Comment: @mklement0 I don't disagree.  Just trying to help him reason it out.

Comment: Aside: There are several bugs in this script which http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is there one of these for batch / .bat files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkdir -p` by itself provides the logic you want, so you could simply do:

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/LOGS" && pushd "$HOME/LOGS" >/dev/null || exit
```

- `mkdir -p` creates the target directory if it doesn't already exists and then changes to it.

  - Note that `mkdir -p` indicates success even if the target already exists.
  - This allows *unconditional* use of `mkdir -p`, without having to worry about whether the directory already exists or not.
- `&& pushd "$HOME/LOGS" >/dev/null` then changes to directory `"$HOME/LOGS"`, suppressing its usual *stdout* output (`>/dev/null`)

  - Note that *stderr* output, unlike in your code, is deliberately *not* suppressed so that error messages don't get lost.
- To be safe, `|| exit` exits the script with a nonzero exit code (to signal failure), if the directory couldn't be created or changed to (because the `exit` command here doesn't explicitly specify an exit code, the previous command's exit code is passed through - which, in this case, is nonzero by definition).

---

Note that I've used `"$HOME/LOGS"`, assuming that's what you really want; i.e., a `LOGS` subdirectory in the current user's home directory.

If instead you  want absolute path `/home/LOGS`, just drop the `$` from your original string.

`$"home/LOGS"` will by default evaluate to `home/LOGS`, i.e., a *relative* path.
The rarely used `$"..."` strings are meant for use in *localization*.

Comment: Thanks, I changed this a bit to get what I need!

Comment: Forgot to edit it, I did actually change it, edited the answer to show